# how to change v-calendar -not vuetify- days formats from (S,M,T,W) to be (Su,Mo,Tu,We)?

Tags: nuxt.js, vcalendar

I'm using [v-calendar](https://vcalendar.io/)  at a **Nuxtjs** app, It displays/render the week days in this format (S,M,T,W,T,F,S) I want to change it to be (Su,Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa).

I've read the [docs](https://vcalendar.io/) and tried to use:formats="DD:MM:YYYY" prop for the component but it didn't work.

Comment: The 2 links above are not the same. Which one are you using exactly?

Comment: Also, give a try to that one: https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/1121#issuecomment-1090450939 That one will also fix quite a few differences down the road IMO, so for the best!

Comment: Thank you very much @kissu, it fixed the issue, I've update the doc link with the right one also.

Comment: Sorry @kissu I'm kinda new to chose answers as the best answer, is there anything I can do for you rather than clicking the up arrow beside the comment ?

Comment: Glad that it fixed the issue! I've posted a comment because I wasn't sure that it would solve your issue. Since it does, I posted an answer. You can click the arrow up and mark it as accepted if you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best approach here is to use [the following](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/1121#issuecomment-1090450939)

```js
:locale="{ id: 'en', firstDayOfWeek: 2, masks: { weekdays: 'WWW' } }"
```

It may fix several things down the road too (like index, formatting, dates/times etc).